# Get one row from multiple rows that have difference of time is 3 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an RFID reader that reads rfid cards . 
so it inserts all cards passed to the RFID machine 
in the read table i have

```
 ReadTable (ReadId, CardNumber , ReadDate , ReaderId )
```

Records for example :

```
1 - 1234  2019-12-27   10:56:02.997   2.1
2 - 1234  2019-12-27   10:57:02.997   2.1
3 - 1234  2019-12-27   10:57:25.997   2.1
4 - 1236  2019-12-27   10:57:02.997   2.1
5 - 1236  2019-12-27   10:58:02.997   2.1
6 - 1236  2019-12-27   10:57:50.997   2.1
7 - 1234  2019-12-27   11:57:50.997   2.1
8 - 1234  2019-12-27   11:56:02.997   2.1
9 - 1234  2019-12-27   12:57:02.997   2.1
10 -1234  2019-12-27   12:57:25.997   2.1
```

So from those 6 records i want the row number 1 ,4 ,7 and 9 only. How can I achieve that?

Comment: After posting 2-3 answers you have changed the input and expected output the way it will appear and even after that not described the logic for 7 and 9 in output.

Comment: @SurajKumar i am sorry because of that .  what i need is : if i have hundred of rows of the same card number i want one row from those who hase different of time is less than 3 minutes with the other rows that has different of time more than 3 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You want `row_number()`

```
select rt.*
from (select rt.*, row_number() over (partition by CardNumber order by ReadDate) as seq
      from ReadTable rt
     ) rt
where seq = 1;
```

Comment: but where is the difference of time in this query @Yogesh Sharma

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the earliest row for each `cardnumber`.  If so, I recommend a correlated subquery:

```
select r.*
from readtable r
where r.readdate = (select min(r2.readdate)
                    from readtable r2
                    where r2.cardnumber = r.cardnumber
                   );
```

With an index on `readtable(cardnumber, readdate)`, this usually has better performance than alternative methods (although performance does depend on a lot of factors, so this is not always true).

EDIT:

I realize that the title suggests slightly different logic.  If you want rows where the previous row is more than three minutes prior, then I would suggest `lag()`:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             lag(readdate) over (partition by cardnumber order by readdate) as prev_readdate
      from readtable r
     ) r
where prev_readdate is null or
      prev_readdate < dateadd(minute, -3, readdate);
```

Comment: what i want is that if a card number  have 8 rows : 4 of them have difference time less than 3 minutes but the other 4 have different time bigger than 3 minutes .so i want one from the first 4 rows and 4 rows from the last 4 rows .
total  = 5 rows